# Rational stable translation length

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $S$ a finite generating set and consider the word metric associated to $S$.

If $g\in G$, define its stable translation length as $l(g)=\lim_n \frac{d(e,g^n)}{n}$.

This number can actually be defined in a more general context: if $G$ acts by isometries on a set $X$, define $l(g)=\lim_n \frac{d(x,g^n\cdot x)}{n}$ and this do not depend on the point $x$, but we restrict our attention to a word metric in the following.

If $G$ is hyperbolic, then there exists $C\in \mathbb{R}$, such that for every $g\in G$, $l(g)\in C\mathbb{Z}$.

My question is the following: are there examples of groups not satisfying this property for the word metric ? More precisely, fixig a word metric on a group $G$, can we find two elements $g,h\in G$ such that $l(g)$ and $l(h)$ are arbitrarily close ? (settled, see the comment of YCor below).

I am specially interested with hyperbolic elements in relatively hyperbolic groups, so another related question is the following: If $G$ is relatively hyperbolic, can one find two hyperbolic elements $g,h$ such that $l(g)$ and $l(h)$ are arbitrarily close ?

As noticed by YCor, it would be enough to find either a loxodromic element with irrational translation length, or to find a relatively hyperbolic group with loxodromic elements of rational translation length but arbitrarily large denominator.

Comment: The proof that $l(g)$ is independent of the basepoint uses hyperbolicity of the space. So I don't think it's true that the number makes sense for any action of a hyperbolic group $G$ on a metric space $X$.

Comment: @HJRW I don't think it does. Fix $x$ and $y$ in $X$. Then, $d(x,g^n\cdot x)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,g^n\cdot y)+d(g^n\cdot y, g^n\cdot x)=2d(x,y)+d(y,g^n\cdot )$.
Thus, $l(g)$ computed with $x$ is lower or equal to $l(g)$ computed with $y$, and by symmetry, the two $l(g)$ coincide.

Comment: You're quite right -- my bad!  I had forgotten where hyperbolicity ends up playing a role.

Comment: Anyway, your question about relatively hyperbolic groups is more or less the same as for arbitrary groups.  If I have an example of a group $G$ with your property, then $G*G$ will be a relatively hyperbolic group with the same property, using the obvious retraction $G*G\to G$.

Comment: @HJRW Okay you're right, thank you. Actually, for relatively hyperbolic group, I am more interested in finding counter example with loxodromic elements. I edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Denis Osin's paper "Relatively hyperbolic groups: Intrinsic geometry, algebraic properties, and algorithmic problems",  arXiv:math/0404040?  In Section 4.3 he considers the sorts of issues you're interested in, although I'm not sure he proves exactly what you want.

Comment: If $G$ is hyperbolic you have a stronger conclusion: $C$ is rational. Probably this follows from the proof, but this already follows from your statement. Indeed if $(G,S)$ is any f.g. group some $g$ with $\ell_S(g)$ irrational, then the free product $G\ast\mathbf{Z}$, where $\mathbf{Z}=\langle t\rangle$, is a hyperbolic group in which $\ell_{S\cup\{t\}}$ takes the value 1 on $t$ and the value $\ell_S(g)$ on $g$; if $G$ is hyperbolic so is $G\ast\mathbf{Z}$ and we get a contradiction. So your first question would better be reformulated as finding $(G,S)$, $g\in G$ with $\ell_S(g)$ irrational.

Comment: Olshanskii developed powerful tools to prescribe various kinds of distortion in finitely generated groups. These can be probably be adapted (if not already done) to provide (a) for any $\alpha\in\,]0,1[$, a f.g. group $(G,S)$ with $g\in G$ satisfying $\ell_S(g)=\alpha$ (b) for any computable (?) $\alpha\in\,]0,1[$, the same with $G$ finitely presented.

Comment: @HJRW Thank you for the reference. Had not checked there yet. However, he's more developping "relatively translation length" there, so not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Of course — to apply Osin’s arguments, one would certainly need to prove a relationship between the relative and absolute translation lengths. But there’s a lot of literature out there about relatively hyperbolic groups, and some of it does consider the absolute word metric.

Comment: @Ycor Yes you are right, you can take $C\in \mathbb{Q}$ and actually, as you said, it's given by the proof. Anyway, I'm more interested in the "discreteness" than in the "rationality". So the question really is "can you find a given $G$ and $S$ such that $l_S(g)$ and $l_S(h)$ can be arbitrarily close" and if so, can you find such an example with $G$ relatively hyperbolic and $g,h$ loxodromic.
Thank you anyway for the reference!

Comment: I said that your question is **equivalent** to the rationality question, which is simpler to formulate, including in the relatively hyperbolic case, since taking the free product by $\mathbf{Z}$ always adds an element with integral stable translation length. Actually this was a little optimistic because we could have a non-discrete subset of $\mathbf{Q}$. Anyway, if you have an element with irrational stable length as well as another with stable length 1, then you have pairs of elements $g,h$ with $\ell(g)$ and $\ell(g)$ arbitrary close.

Comment: And googling yields *G. Conner, Arch. Math. 69.4 265-274 1997
A class of finitely generated groups with irrational translation numbers* (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000130050120): polycyclic with an element with irrational stable length. We there's a polycyclic group and generating subset and an irrational $r$ such that the set of stable translation lengths contains $\mathbf{N}\cup\mathbf{N}r$, which contains arbitrary close points.

Comment: @YCor Thank you very much for these. It settles the first question then. Not the second though. If you do a free product with $G$ and another group, you get arbitrarily close translation lengths for elements in the parabolic subgroup $G$, but maybe not that easily for loxodromic elements.

Comment: To conclude, your last question (about loxodromics) is equivalent to: does there exist a relatively hyperbolic group $G$ and generating subset $S$ satisfying either (a) or (b), where (a) means: "there exists a loxodromic with irrational stable length" and (b) means for every $n$ there exists $q\ge n$ and a loxodromic with stable length $p/q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your last comment. If $S$ generates $G$ relatively hyperbolic, take a free product $G'$ of $G$ with $\langle t\rangle$ with $S'=S\cup\{t\}$, and $L_{G,S}$ is the set of stable lengths of loxodromics of $G$, then $L_{G',S'}$ contains $L_{G,S}\cup\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: @YCor Yes you're right, and so as you said, the question reduces to find a relatively hyperbolic group with a loxodromic element with irrational translation length. What I was saying is that in the example you gave, the elements we get with irrational translation length are parabolic, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, there exist finitely generated groups having non-discrete translation spectra. (There seems to be only a few examples though, it would be interesting to have more.) About relatively hyperbolic groups, we have the following statement:

> **Proposition.** *Let $G$ be a relatively hyperbolic group. There exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that the translation number of every hyperbolic element is a rational $>\epsilon$.*

The fact that the translation number is rational is actually quite general. See in [my other answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429689/122026) for the sketch of a proof that Morse elements in finitely generated groups have rational translation numbers. In order to bound below the translation number, we can consider the action of $G$ on the hyperbolic space $X$ obtained by coning-off $G$ over its parabolic subgroups, i.e. $X$ is the graph obtained from (the Cayley graph of) $G$ by adding an edge between any two vertices that belong to a common parabolic subgroup. The action of $G$ on $X$ is acylindrical and an element of $G$ is loxodromic in $X$ if and only if it is hyperbolic in $G$. Therefore, the translation length in $X$ of a hyperbolic $g \in G$ cannot be arbitrarily small. (See for instance Lemma 2.1 in Fujiwara's article *Subgroups generated by two pseudo-Anosov elements in a mapping class group I*.) But the obvious map $G \to X$ is $1$-Lipschitz, so the translation length of $g$ in $X$ is at most the translation number of $g$ in $G$. The desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I eventually managed to find a proof of your stated Proposition. This is Proposition 7.8 in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.10849.pdf. I should have answered my own question. Anyway, I'm going to accept yours since it answers a more general question.